# Using htaccess to redirect URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using the following code which works great if there is a sub file/folder, e.g. **domain.com/home.html**

The problem is, if I am just accessing **domain.com**, it tries to redirect to **domain.com/index.html.var**

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.domain.com/$1"
```

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and why do you have `RewriteOptions inherit` ?

Comment: It's the website's home folder. Not sure about the inherit thing.

Comment: Comment out `RewriteOptions inherit` line. Does your root folder have an index file?

Comment: I got it to work by taking out the `inherit` line and creating a file named "index" where.htaccess lives.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DirectoryIndex htaccess directive

```
DirectoryIndex index.html home.html
```